# Chat box doesn't full scroll down when new message is sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so i'm making a chatbox like application using html, css, php, and JS. I've stumbled across a problem where after the enter button is clicked I would have it run

```
 $("#MESSAGES").scrollTop($("#MESSAGES")[0].scrollHeight);
```

(#MESSAGES being the ID for my chatbox log) The message would then do it's magic and appear on the screen but not scrolled to.  Although it does scroll down it doesn't fully scroll down to show the new msg unless i click enter again.
is there anyway i can simply hit the enter key and have the message appear on the bottom of the div right after the enter button?

```
.chatbox {
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 590px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: none;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

This here is the styles for the div in which the messages (message logs) are kept in.

```
.chatlogs {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

This here is the actual div in which the messages appear in.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Can you include what you're getting after doing this code. I mean like some fiddle or at least an image.

Comment: use `$("#MESSAGES").scrollTop(9e9)` to go to the bottom.

Comment: It works the same as the previous scrollTop code & requires me to hit enter twice to fully scroll down and see the new message @dandavis

Comment: you must be calling it before the new message is appended, i don't see how else it wouldn't be all the way down...